# java.io.FileNotFoundException on Properties FileInputStream in CMD

Tags: java, properties, path, filenotfoundexception

I'm loading a Property file with the following method:

> ```
> private final String utitt=Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();//
> ...
> properties.load(new FileInputStream(utitt+"/beallitasok/lang.set"));
> ...
> ```

This works fine within NetBeans without problems, but the jar file fails in command prompt:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\java\IKE\dist\beallitasok\lang.set
>   (A rendszer nem találja a megadott fájlt)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)
>           at IKE.IKE.fordit(IKE.java:1519)
>           at IKE.IKE.access$300(IKE.java:81)
>           at IKE.IKE$IngatlanokAblak.(IKE.java:9411)
>           at IKE.IKE.(IKE.java:544)
>           at IKE.IKE.main(IKE.java:697)

I've copied the "beallitasok" directory there (to c:\java\IKE\dist in my case), so the file is actually there. I'm using some files to translate certain strings and save/read some settings. I've checked whether i'm just blind, so just opened the file with a "more C:\java\IKE\dist\beallitasok\lang.set" command and it works.
Where or how shall i search for a clue? I'm not a pro, so thanks for any help.
PS: (A rendszer nem találja a megadott fájlt) = The System can't find the specified file. Translated from the Hungarian language.

Comment: Can you provide the command line you are using to launch the jar?

Comment: Hello bradimus, there you go with path: C:\java\IKE\dist>java -jar "IKE.jar"